# Between Sanhedrin 108b & Sanhedrin.38b

Tags: talmud-gemara, midrash, messiah, abraham

**According to [Sanhedrin 108b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.108b.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):**

> *Rav Ḥana bar Leva’ei says that Shem the Great said to Eliezer, servant of Abraham: When the four great kings of the east and the west
> came upon you to wage war with Abraham, what did you do? Eliezer said
> to him: The Holy One, Blessed be He, brought Abraham and placed him to
> His right, and we would throw dust and it became swords, and we threw
> straw and it became arrows, as it is stated: “A Psalm of David. The
> Lord says to my master: Sit to My right, until I make your enemies
> your footstool” (Psalms 110:1), and it is written: “Who has raised up
> one from the east at whose steps victory attends? He gives nations
> before him, and makes him rule over kings; his sword makes them as the
> dust, his bow as driven straw” (Isaiah 41:2).*

**According to [Sanhedrin.38b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.38b.17?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):**

> *The Gemara clarifies: This works out well for almost all the verses, as they describe an action taken by God, but what is there to say
> concerning the verse: “I beheld till thrones were placed”? The Gemara
> answers: One throne is for Him and one throne is for David, i.e., the
> messiah, as it is taught in a baraita: One throne is for Him and one
> throne is for David; this is the statement of Rabbi Akiva. Rabbi Yosei
> said to him: Akiva! Until when will you desacralize the Divine
> Presence by equating God with a person? Rather, the correct
> interpretation is that both thrones are for God, as one throne is for
> judgment and one throne is for righteousness.The Gemara asks: Did
> Rabbi Akiva accept this explanation from Rabbi Yosei or did he not
> accept it from him? The Gemara suggests: Come and hear a proof to the
> matter from what was taught in another baraita, as it is taught in a
> baraita: One throne is for judgment and one throne is for
> righteousness; this is the statement of Rabbi Akiva. Rabbi Elazar ben
> Azarya said to him: Akiva! What are you doing near, i.e., discussing,
> matters of aggada? Go near tractates Nega’im and Oholot, which examine
> the complex halakhot of ritual purity, where your knowledge is
> unparalleled. Rather, the correct interpretation is that while both
> thrones are for God, one is for a throne and one is for a stool. There
> is a throne for God to sit upon, and a stool that serves as His
> footstool.*

It seems that Rabbi Akiva, believed that “I beheld till thrones were placed” means LITERALLY that there will be One throne for God and one throne for The Messiah,which is not acceptable as it would desacralize the Divine Presence by equating God with a person.

On the other hand, Sanhedrin 108b, [Psalms 110:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.110.1?lang=bi&with=Sanhedrin&lang2=en) is interpreted as a reference to The Holy One, Blessed be He, brought Abraham and placed him to His right. Wouldn't that desacralize the Divine Presence, just as the interpretation of Rabbi Akiva?

Comment: The Ben Yehoyada mentions that חֶסֶד - lovingkindness, represents the "right side". The left side is represented by justice. Thus, Michael the Archangle. Michael is called the prince of kindness and water (Midrash Tanchuma, Vayigash 6). Thus, G-d sent Michael to help Avraham Avinu. This all can be found in footnote 60 on that daf in the ArtScroll version. So it seems, and just read Rashi, that this does not imply that Avraham literally sits on the right side on the Throne.

Comment: One possibility is that Rav Chana bar Livai (Sanh. 108b) follows the approach of Rabbi 'Akiva (Sanh. 38b), that this type of figurative description does not in fact profane the Divine Presence. Also note that the Sefaria translation is imprecise; Rabbi Yosei doesn't mean that Rabbi 'Akiva was literally equating King David with the Almighty, but instead (per Rashi) that it was inappropriate for Rabbi 'Akiva to use imagery that places King David next to the Divine Presence (which itself is merely a Divine representation of the Almighty's Presence and not the Almighty incarnate).